# undefined reference to _start

Tags: c++, c, embedded

Собираю проект для armv6-m cortex-m1 на C++(gcc). Использую флаг -nostdlib (так нужно). ld не находит _start. Понимаю, что нужно прицепить crt0 из newlib. Цепляю. Не находит exit и что-то еще. Цепляю. И так далее... Подскажите православный способ подцепить все что нужно. Не использую startup.s. Векторы прерываний в заголовчном файле на C++. И вообще это C++ или нет? почему ctr0 и тд не цепляется автоматом?

Comment: Можно вместо линкера снова запустить  g++, передав ему все объектные файлы. Он поймёт, что нужно запустить линкер, и сам прицепит к нему нужные зависимости. Для этого в Makefile нужно найти что-то вроде `ld=($toolchain)ld` и заменить на `ld=($toolchain)g++`. Не помню синтаксис Makefile, но суть такая.

Comment: makefile пишу сам и не трогаю ld непосредственно

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Добавил -nostartfiles и по сбросу помимо всего прочего вызываю main. Я не разбирался в функции _start(), но что-бы она не делала - мне это не нужно. Всем спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-nostartfiles и по сбросу помимо всего прочего вызывать main. Я не разбирался в функции _start(), но что-бы она не делала это не нужно